# Problema con Background-img en React

Tags: reactjs, css3, imagen, webpack, background

Hola a todos tengo un problema con el Background-img: url('')
estoy utilizando React y he programado el file-loader correctamente en webpack, al compilar las imágenes se soportan bien mas cuando intento colocar una imagen como backgroud-img se rompe el código lo raro es que solo me pasa con imágenes jpg y png pero funciona normal para svg
no entiendo donde esta el error y me tiene jodido alguna ayuda por favor, nuevamente confirmo estoy usando React

Comment: Hola @Bruno. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda. También, puede consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien lo que quieres hacer pero bueno este ejemplo quizas te ayude

```
import React from 'react';

const Componente = () =>{
  let urlDeLaImagen = "https://ruta.a/la/imagen.png"
   return (
     <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${urlDeLaImagen})`}} ></div>
   )
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Considera leer [answer] y explicar tu aporte